# How to create new columns based on values of specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create new columns by multiplying a given lists to specific rows in column.

```
Here is my df;

d = {'ID':['ZZ7','ZZ7','ZZ7','ZZ7','ZZ7','ZZ7','ZZ7','RR6','RR6','RR6','RR6','RR6','RR6','RR6',
     'DD5','DD5','DD5','DD5','DD5','DD5','DD5'],'Section': ['1H','1H','2H','2H','2H','3R','3R','1H',
     '1H','1H','2H','2H','3R','3R','1H','1H','2H','2H','3R','3R','3R'],
'A': [1,2,5,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,1,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,1],
     'B': [2,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Here are the lists to be used to create new cols.

RateB_1H = [1,2,3,4]
RateB_2H = [3,4,5,6]
RateB_3R = [1,3,5,7]

RateA_1H = [1,1,2,1]
RateA_2H = [2,3,1,2]
RateA_3R = [1,3,2,1]
```

By selecting the values assiciated with specific Section, 
`i.e. df['Rate_A']` will be created by selecting the corresponding values associted with `df['Section']`

```
df[df.Section=='1H'] from RateA_1H, 
df[df.Section=='2H'] from RateA_2H,
df[df.Section=='3R'] from RateA_3R,
```

And similarly to `df['Rate_B']`.

```
df[df.Section=='1H'] from RateB_1H, 
df[df.Section=='2H'] from RateB_2H,
df[df.Section=='3R'] from RateB_3R,
```

**Which looks like the following (by brute-force).**

```
    ID  Section A   B   Rate_B  Rate_A
0   ZZ7   1H    1   2      1    1
1   ZZ7   1H    2   3      2    1
2   ZZ7   2H    5   1      3    2
3   ZZ7   2H    1   1      4    3
4   ZZ7   2H    1   3      5    1
5   ZZ7   3R    2   1      1    1
6   ZZ7   3R    1   1      3    3
7   RR6   1H    1   3      1    1
8   RR6   1H    2   1      2    1
9   RR6   1H    3   1      3    2
10  RR6   2H    1   2      3    2
11  RR6   2H    1   2      4    3
12  RR6   3R    3   3      1    1
13  RR6   3R    1   1      3    3
14  DD5   1H    1   2      1    1
15  DD5   1H    2   1      2    1
16  DD5   2H    2   2      3    2
17  DD5   2H    3   1      4    3
18  DD5   3R    1   1      1    1
19  DD5   3R    2   2      3    3
20  DD5   3R    1   1      5    2
```

I would appreciate any help to create the above columns for a large dataframe.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "multiply". In your example, it seems that you just map each "1H" to "4" (and this is the solution suggested by hacker315). Is this your goal? all elements of list AvgA_1H are equal?

Comment: @luca.vercelli you are right I dont multiply anything at this time. But eventually I will create new columns "Exp_A" and "Exp_B" by multiplying "Rate_A" by "A" and similarly for "Exp_B". I have edited the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how you calculated the Rate_xxx columns. Colud you please fix on a single line (e.g. line 3) and explain how did you calculated the value Rate_A=3 ?

Comment: @luca.vercelli, df.section == 2H takes values from RateA==2H. 
If we take g = df[df['Section']=='2H']
So, the corresponding values will [2,3,1] from RateA_2H. 
Hence the Rate_A at index 3 is 3

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, it first copies column and then uses replace accordingly:

```
df['Rate_A'] = df['A']
df['Rate_B'] = df['B']

df['Rate_B'] = df['Rate_B'].str.replace({"1H":1, "2H": 2, "3R": 3})
df['Rate_A'] = df['Rate_A'].str.replace({"1H":4, "2H": 5, "3R": 6})

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you @hacker315, could you please see the edited question. Apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could split the dataframe in three parts, and operate separately  on each one.

I am assuming that the lists RateA_xxx are as long as needed.

```
AvgA_1H = [1,1,2,1,0,0,0]
AvgA_2H = [2,3,1,2,0,0,0]
AvgA_3R = [1,3,2,1,0,0,0]

oneh = df[df['Section']=='1H']
twoh = df[df['Section']=='2H']
threer = df[df['Section']=='3R']

oneh['Rate_A'] = AvgA_1H
twoh['Rate_A'] = AvgA_2H
threer['Rate_A'] = AvgA_3R

pd.concat([oneh,twoh,threer])
```

Comment: Within each groupby ID objects, if Section = 1H then Rate_A will take values from RateA_1H. For ex. in ID=RR6, Rate_A will take the first three values from RateA_1H. In case of ID=ZZ7, then Rate_A will take the first 2 values from Rate_1H...Again, apologies for not explaining myself clearly. A bit nervous posting for the first time.